# javascript audio object - present audio player from .ogg blob

Tags: javascript, html, audio, async-await

I'm attempting to fetch an ogg audio file from a remote server and present a player to the user. I'm using the below code.

This results in no output. But inspecting the code reveals that the audio tag is in the container:

```
<audio preload="auto" src="blob:null/eaed3b36-8c17-4522-8a24-6265a180bf5a"></audio>
```

However it appears greyed out in Firefox's inspector. The error property of the DOM audio object is *null*. So as far as I can tell the audio player should be displayed.

**How do I present an audio player to the user from and audio object with .ogg format?**

A final point, I notice that, when I [go to](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Dial_up_modem_noises.ogg) the link directly, wikimedia uses the video tag - is there a way to translate the audio object to a video tag?

```js
let url1 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Dial_up_modem_noises.ogg"

async function getAudFromUrl(url) {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  data = await response.blob();
  let audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(data);
  return audio;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function() {
  let au = await getAudFromUrl(url1);
  let el = document.getElementById("audio1")
  el.appendChild(au)
})
```

```css
  .container {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          }
```

```html
  <div class = 'container'>
    <div id = 'audio1'></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it using a video tag (the `'audio1' autoplay="" controls=""` tags were important.

```js
let url1 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Dial_up_modem_noises.ogg"

async function getAudFromUrl(url) {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  data = await response.blob();
  let audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(data);
  return audio;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function() {
  let au = await getAudFromUrl(url1);
  let el = document.getElementById("audio1")
  el.src = au.src
})
```

```html
  <div class = 'container'>
    <video id = 'audio1' autoplay="" controls="" ></video>
  </div>
```